# Determine if a string appears in the first 100 or last 100 text node characters of an html content object

Tags: php, xpath

Given a string of text "my search phrase", inside an html content block, how would you determine if the string appears within the first 100 or last 100 non tag-based characters of the document? (Don't count html tags, only text nodes)

Example, this would return true...

<p>This html text block contains <b>My Search Phrase</b>, because it appears in the first 100 characters of the content.</p>

Comment: See my answer for a complete and detailed solution.

Comment: Including the head or just in the body textnodes? and should whitespace be taken into account?

Comment: Just the body, actually, I'd load the html into memory as a subset of the document body. It's the "post" object of WordPress, which is enclosed in a div with ID="content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would you determine if the string
>   appears within the first 100 or last
>   100 non tag-based characters of the
>   document?

In the absence of any definition of "non-tag-based characters, **I assume these are any characters of the string value of the document: `string(/)`.**

**Therefore**:

```
contains(substring(/,1,100),'my search phrase')
```

returns `true()` exactly when the first 100 characters of the string value of the document contain the string `'my search phrase'`.

**Similarly**:

```
contains(substring(/, string-length(/)-99),'my search phrase')
```

returns `true()` exactly when the last 100 characters of the string value of the document contain the string `'my search phrase'`.

Therefore:

```
  contains(substring(/,1,100),'my search phrase')
or
  contains(substring(/, string-length(/)-99),'my search phrase')
```

returns `true()` exactly when the first or last 100 characters of the string value of the document contain the string `'my search phrase'`.

Comment: if my string is contained in variable $myString, how do I test the contains method in your example? $myString.contains(substr(/,1,100),'my search phrase') using PHP?

Comment: @scott-b: Just replace `"/"` with `"$myString"` everywhere in the expressions in my answer.